# Android to perform query when we have multiple value for one column

Tags: android, sql

I have 100 records and each record is assigned a unique id. now i want to get the records from table having unique id(12,4,6,7,8). what is the best why to do it.

Comment: Use IN clause in your WHERE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select * from TABLE where id in (12,4,6,7,8)

http://www.techonthenet.com/sqlite/in.php

Note: "select *" is only for the sample, you should avoid * in your query.